# Transformation of a random variable, example.

Tags: probability, statistics

This is an example from Wasserman's "All of Statistics" that I don't understand:

If we have $X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(-1, 3)$ and we want to find the pdf of $Y = X^2$ if the density of $X$ is:

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    1/4, & \text{if $-1<x<3$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I would consider the set $A_y = \{ x: x \leq \sqrt{y}\}$ and perform the integral $\int_{A_y} f_X(x) \, dx$ that is equal to the cdf $F_Y(y)$ and then derivating we get $f_Y(y) = F'_Y(y)$. This is what the book teaches.

But he considers two separated cases; one with $0 < y < 1$ and the other with $1 < y < 9$. Why that separation for $y = 1$? I can't see any reason for that, any inflection point or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's necessary to consider the cases $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $1<y\leq 9$ separately because $X\geq -1$:

If $0\leq y\leq 1$ then $0\leq \sqrt{y}\leq 1$ as well, so $X^2\leq y$ implies that $-\sqrt{y}\leq X\leq y$.

On the other hand, if $1<y\leq 9$ then $\sqrt{y}>1$, so since $X\geq -1$, $X^2\leq y$ implies that $-1\leq X\leq \sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I still don't get it. I follow your reason but I still don't understand why X = -1 is so important to divide the interval. Could you elaborate more, please?

Comment: Why don't you try drawing the support of $X$ and seeing what happens in the two cases?

Comment: If the interval of X were from Uniform (1, 3) and 1/2 instead of 1/4 there were no need to study the two cases apart?

Comment: Yes, in that case $X^2\leq y$ implies that $1\leq X\leq \sqrt{y}$ for $1\leq y\leq 9$.